# How to post json object with multiple values to the Controller from Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax, javascript-objects

I have this Ajax post working for a single value but I need it to work with multiple values. What am I missing?

I have already tried to make the public class 'Value' a List AND Guid[]. I have tried to adjust the method parameter to List AND Value[]. Not sure what else to try.

```
Class:
public class Value
{
    public Guid TimeId { get; set; }
}

Method:
public IActionResult ApproveAllTimesheets([FromBody]Value information)

View JS:
function SubAll() {
        var selectedValues = $('#timesheet').DataTable().column(0).checkboxes.selected().toArray();

        var instructions = {};
        for (var TimeId in selectedValues) {
            instructions[TimeId] = { TimeId: selectedValues[TimeId] };
        }

        var inst = JSON.stringify(instructions);

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Admin/ApproveAllTimesheets",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: inst,
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus) {
                if (xhr.status == 401) { alert("Session Expired!"); window.location = "/Account"; }
                else {
                    alert('Content load failed!', "info");
                }
            }
        });
    };
```

If I send through this object it works but I need to send through multiple values like my ajax post will do.

var instructions = { TimeId: "13246578-1234-7894-4562-456789123456" };

**UPDATE #1**
I found a structure that works for me by extending the class, now I just need to figure out how to create the correct object and array combination.

```
New Classes:
public class ValueContainer
{
    public List<Value> MasterIds { get; set; }
}

public class Value
{
    public Guid TimeId { get; set; }
}

Method:
 public IActionResult ApproveAllTimesheets([FromBody]ValueContainer information)

Structure I need now (this works hard coded):
 var jsonObject = {
            "MasterIds": [{ TimeId: "13246578-1234-7894-4562-456789123450" }, { TimeId: "13246578-1234-7894-4562-456789123451" }, { TimeId: "13246578-1234-7894-4562-456789123452" }]
        };
```

I'm still new to this stuff but what I see is that jsonObject is an object with a Key 'MasterIds' and the corresponding values are an array of objects with the key 'TimeId'...is this a correct evaluation?...and how to create it in code please?

Comment: I see now that what you posted was correct for what I need to finish this now...too funny!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You neec to create an array of objects and then set it in the container object :

```
 var instructions = []; // an array 
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedValues.length; i++) {
        instructions.push({ TimeId: selectedValues[i] };
    }

var Value = {TimeId: instructions}; // creating object with property TimeId as array of guid

var inst = JSON.stringify(Value);
.......
....... your ajax code
```

and your class property should also be of type array:

```
public Guid[] TimeId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Did not work for me but the above Update #1 is 99% there...please look.